# When adding nil to tableHeaderView cant show it again

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableheader

I have added table Header in the TableView in Storyboard, I want to hide/show this header.

I have a segmented control, and want the header to show in one of the segments.

To hide the header in one segment I used: `tableView.tableHeaderView = nil`
 and this hides it.
In other segments, to unhide the header I used:

```
if tableView.tableHeaderView == nil {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableViewHeader
}
```

but the header does not shown again. How to solve this?

Comment: Have you check the value of self.tableViewHeader after set tableView.tableHeaderView = nil .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set

```
tableView.tableHeaderView == nil
```

**Than You create a local variable to store tableView.tableHeaderView  on viewDidLoad as this**

```
self.tableViewHeader = tableView.tableHeaderView
```

than check

```
if tableView.tableHeaderView == nil 
{
 tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableViewHeader
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide and Show Table Header like that:

```
// Show header
```

tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(44)), animated: true)

```
// Hide header
```

tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0)), animated: true)

Comment: I'm using swift

Comment: I have update my code in Swift and thanks to remind me.

Comment: tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(64)), animated: true) this is great with me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

```
tableView.tableHeaderView.isHidden = true
 if tableView.tableHeaderView.isHidden {
  tableView.tableHeaderView.isHidden = false }
```

or

```
tableView.tableHeaderView.removeFromSuperview
```

Comment: this leads to show empty space in the place of header when I hide it

Comment: then simple do tableView.tableHeaderView.removeFromSuperview

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
 @IBAction func segmentButtonClicked(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
            switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                if demoTableView.tableHeaderView == nil {
                    var view1: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width :320,height: 60));
                    var label: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width :320,height: 60))
                    label.text = "header text"
                    view1.addSubview(label);
                    demoTableView.tableHeaderView = view1
                }
               demoTableView.reload()
            case 1:
                 if demoTableView.tableHeaderView != nil {
                     demoTableView.tableHeaderView = nil
                 }
                demoTableView.reload()
            default:
                break
            }
        }
```